# Is there a way to embed a PowerBi dashboard into a wiki page?

Tags: html, iframe, powerbi, mediawiki, wiki

I’m trying to set up a PowerBi dashboard into a wiki page without having to click on a link to go to an external page. I’ve tried using the iframe html link provided but it doesn’t work out.

I’ve watched a couple of videos on YouTube but none of the options work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.